# scp from AWS EC2 takes very long time

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scp

I am trying to scp a directory from my EC2 instance. I am using the following command:

`scp -i "keyPair.pem" -r ubuntu@ec2.....com:~/targetDirectory ./`

It seems like it is working and I see initially names of files being copied, but then I see the following output for a very long time (cancelled the operation after 5 minutes of this):

```
343f1933ac9543d7a1f01485c05240da92a59b          100%  233     0.2KB/s   00:00
7179795a244d484c59cdfb4279173cbbea8fc9          100%  229     0.2KB/s   00:00
85df1721798f6580e5612bc0725d3fac4afbd9          100% 1852     1.8KB/s   00:00
e98e3f2a32409d91a00986349c66a031e288d2          100%  437     0.4KB/s   00:00
d1b67475405284e3dac312f92ade101571329f          100%  867     0.9KB/s   00:00
64ea541f6892f18f1f36ce8369109ae3d949c3          100%  650     0.6KB/s   00:00
b2fb3f4d7a4c54a2defb35bfdd33ca6aaa46f2          100%  487     0.5KB/s   00:00
4101f13526772891c89b9c81feb8c89b8d08a3          100%  346     0.3KB/s   00:00
612c85081563ca33523e691df71c3d62aaf067          100%  531     0.5KB/s   00:00
4fd27b541733586269f71b24bee6c695693205          100%  357     0.4KB/s   00:00
ee8b464484d1d9292340545cab02c5f777e1a6          100% 1269     1.2KB/s   00:00
```

Does anyone if I'm doing anything wrong/what's going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the speed of transfer. The throughput is very low `200 bytes/sec to 500 bytes/sec`. Check your network connection. Is there some throttling enabled? Even then I have never seen such a low low transfer speed.

Use `scp -v` to show the progress. It is likely the next file being transferred is big and takes a long time (> 5 mins) to download it.

Comment: Thanks, how would I check if throttling is enabled?

Comment: The output when using the -v option is:

Comment: Sending file modes: C0444 17 26dfeeb6e641a33dae4961196235bdb965b21b
Sink: C0444 17 26dfeeb6e641a33dae4961196235bdb965b21b
26dfeeb6e641a33dae4961196235bdb965b21b          100%   17     0.0KB/s   00:00
Sending file modes: C0444 239 2f084236ef0c2c7223b5ddc8bdd768f8350e48
Sink: C0444 239 2f084236ef0c2c7223b5ddc8bdd768f8350e48
2f084236ef0c2c7223b5ddc8bdd768f8350e48          100%  239     0.2KB/s   00:00

Comment: `scp -v` output is not helpful. What is the instance type? The physical machine that runs your instance may be over provisioned. If possible, stop the instance and start it again (not reboot). AWS will move your instance to a different physical machine which may not be heavily loaded. Try it.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was using the DNS instead of public IP... Disconnect and connect using the IP provided...